# what are all aggregation stages that are supported by mongodb's SBE?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup, mongodb-sbe

[https://www.mydbops.com/blog/mongodbs-slot-based-query-execution-engine/#mongodb's-sbe-pipeline-optimizations-5](https://www.mydbops.com/blog/mongodbs-slot-based-query-execution-engine/#mongodb%27s-sbe-pipeline-optimizations-5)

There doesn't appear to be a exhaustive list of all aggregation stages supported by SBE.

I need this list because I need to structure aggregation pipelines involving `$lookup`. However, one of the conditions for `$lookup` to use SBE is that all preceding stages must be SBE supported as well.

So for example, I need to know if this query supports SBE:

```
db.aggregate([
  { $match: { } },
  { $limit: { } },
  { $set: { } },
  { $lookup: { } },
])
```

I know that the `$match` stage is supported by SBE. But no documentation on `$limit` or `$set`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [does mongodb v6 use the SBE engine for the $match stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78123678/does-mongodb-v6-use-the-sbe-engine-for-the-match-stage)